# assign an <a> tag to a div using javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm working on a website on WordPress and **the following code is being generated by a WordPress theme** several times:

```
<div style="max-width: 700px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" id="post-394" class="  width2 white all portfolio-post portfolio-thumbnail no-padding"> 
    <figure class="portfolio-thumbnail-container">
        <div class="thumbnail-image">
            <img src="http://mysiste.com/relaunch/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/hota2xFeaturedImage.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="hota2xFeaturedImage" height="320" width="700">
        </div>
        <figcaption class="portfolio-thumbnail-caption portfolio-thumbnail-attachments text-right">
            <h5 class="heading heading-underlined portfolio-thumbnail-heading">
                <a href="http://mysiste.com/relaunch/portfolio/mysite/">My site</a>
            </h5>
            <ul class="portfolio-category list-inline">
            </ul>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>               
</div>
```

And I need to move the `<a>` tag on each generated piece of code to "wrap" another section of the code, It should be like this:

```
<div style="max-width: 700px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" id="post-394" class="  width2 white all portfolio-post portfolio-thumbnail no-padding">
    <a href="http://mysiste.com/relaunch/portfolio/mysite/">    
        <figure class="portfolio-thumbnail-container">
            <div class="thumbnail-image">
                <img src="http://mysiste.com/relaunch/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/hota2xFeaturedImage.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="hota2xFeaturedImage" height="320" width="700">
            </div>
            <figcaption class="portfolio-thumbnail-caption portfolio-thumbnail-attachments text-right">
                <h5 class="heading heading-underlined portfolio-thumbnail-heading">
                    My site
                </h5>
                <ul class="portfolio-category list-inline">
                </ul>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>       
    </a>        
</div>
```

Since I can't edit the code because everything is generated by WordPress shortcodes. Is there a way to do it using JavaScript or jQuery for all the generated divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in javascript without jQuery

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.width2.white.all.portfolio-post.portfolio-thumbnail.no-padding figure figcaption h5 a'), function(a) {
    var h5 = a.parentNode;
    var figure = h5.parentNode.parentNode;
    var div = figure.parentNode;

    div.appendChild(a);
    h5.textContent = a.textContent;
    a.textContent = '';
    a.appendChild(figure);
});
```

`div.width2.white.all.portfolio-post.portfolio-thumbnail.no-padding figure figcaption h5 a` doesn't have to be so nasty - whittle it down to maybe something like `div.portfolio-post a` or something like `div[id^="post-"] a` as per the jQuery answer

Comment: This is a better solution, but the final issue is that the text into <h5> tag is being printed outside the div, if you can tell me how to hide it we'll be done :D

Comment: That must be a style issue ... the html is exactly as you require

Comment: @Manu You should try writing some code on your own. Are you expecting us to write even a full stop for you?

Comment: if you want to hide the text in h5, remove the line that says `h5.textContent = a.textContent`

Comment: No I don't in fact I was trying to remove it by myself, using the attr function, and @JaromandaX is right, maybe it's a css issue, thank you very much for your help guys!

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy  just need it as a quick solution, I'm not expecting to anybody make the work for me. 
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

There might be cleaner solution, but this will get the job done in **jQuery**

```
$(function(){    // is runned after the page loads
    $('.portfolio-thumbnail-container').each(function() {
         var a = $(this).find('a');   // extract <a/> in a variable
         a.parent().html(a.html());   // replace the content of a's parent with a's content
         $(this).wrap(a.empty()));    // wrap the thumbnail-contailer with the <a> tag, replacing the old content of a with ''
    });
});
```

Note that with this solution all elements with class `portofolio-thumbnail-container` will be altered and it requires that the 'a' tag is always inside the `h5`. If your page does not meet these, you may need to change some selectors. If you're having problems with that leave a comment.

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2gtq7qo9/1/

Answer (score 0):

You just have to apply that div id

```
document.getElementById("lnk").href = "https://jsfiddle.net/Parth_Raval/67n70pe2";
```

Answer (score -1):

This is very easy with jQuery:

```
$(".portfolio-thumbnail-container").click(function(){
   window.location.href = "http://mysiste.com/relaunch/portfolio/mysite/";
});
```

Comment: But it will trigger the opening action of the link, it has to be a link instead open the new window once it's clicked. Besides each generated piece of code will not redirect to the same link.